# Can someone help me understand this recursion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Here is the code:

```
func [] _ = 0
func (head:tail) num
| head > num = func tail num
| head <= num = head + (func tail num)

main = print(func [4,1,2,5,7,6] 2 * 3)
```

Here is my solution:

```
4 + func[1,2,5,7,6] 6 
    -> 1 + func[2,5,7,6] 6 
           -> 2 + func[5,7,6] 6 
                  -> 5 + func[7,6] 6 
                         -> func[6] 6
                            -> 6 + func[] 6
 ---> 4 + 1 + 2 + 5 + 6 = 18
```

But I checked in online compiler solution is 9, where did I make a mistake I don't get it. It is pretty simple code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression providing the argument to `print` should be understood as

```
(func [4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6] 2) * 3
```

not

```
func [4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 6] (2 * 3)
```

because function application takes precedence over any infix operator.